# iOS heapshot analysis, UIImage & NSData

Tags: ios, memory-management, heapshot

I used the heapshot analysis, and it pointed to the first two lines reproduced below. It seems like I am releasing all the memory I am allocating. I don't see how the memory is accumulating.

```
        NSData* data = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archivePath];
        UIImage *view = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];        

        background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:view];
        [view release];
        [display addSubview: background];
        if(fileExists){
            [background addSubview: newView];
        }
        [background release];
```

Comment: Do you use ARC ? Try use `Products > Analyze` in xCode

Comment: I don't use ARC. I ran the static analyzer and none of the errors seem  related to the above segment of code.

Comment: You never remove the old background from display, unless you are doing it somewhere else.  It will be retained and live forever in that case (until display is released).

Comment: You never release the `data` too.

Comment: I thought that I don't need to release the data since it doesn't allocate memory. I tried releasing it immediately after and the application crashed.

Comment: Actually that's correct - `data` is autoreleased, don't release it explicitly. With the "typos" fixed (don't type, always cut and paste from actual sources) I no longer see an error here.